# Combinatorics and sequence of alphabets.

Tags: combinatorics, discrete-mathematics, permutations

**Question:**
Find the number of $n$ long sequences of letters $a$, $b$, $c$ where $a$ cannot appear on odd numerical positions, positions are numbered from 1.

**My solution:**
We find all the possible sequences without any restrictions and subtract them from the restricted cases.

$$ since \ there \ are \ 3  \ digits \ we \ can \ make \ 3n \ possible \ length \ of \ sequences$$
**Case 1:**
We keep the a in the 1st place i.e. odd place and permute the rest of the 
options.

$$ {3 \choose 1  } { 3n \choose 1 } {2! }$$
Here is choose 1 alphabet from 1, and multiply with, 1 alphabet chosen from n places and the remaining permuted to fit the other places.

Or was i supposed to do it considering the even places left in 3n spaces and fit the a's there?

Please correct me for any wrong doing.
Thanks!

Comment: Your question is very unclear.  Why do you think there are $3n$ possible lengths of sequences?  Why isn't the problem for *fixed* length $n$?

Comment: Not sure I follow.  We have $3$ choices for every even slot and $2$ for every odd slot, so roughly speaking the answer is about $3^{\frac n2}\times 2^{\frac n2}$ (you need to handle even and odd $n$ separately).

Comment: @DavidG.Stork the problem isn't for a fixed length n, the n is of variable length, if there are 3 words, then 5 sequences will have, 3x5 = length of 15. That's how I deduced it to be true. But i'm not sure.

Comment: @Prathik $\rm a,b,c$ form the alphabet used to make the word (each used none-or-many times). $~$ The variable $n$ is the *count of letters in the word*. $~$ The length of the word is $n$.

Comment: @Prathik:  According to you lulu's and Graham Kemp's answers are then wrong.  Yes?

Comment: @DavidG.Stork I don't mean to say he's wrong, he has a point where he says we have to keep separate cases for odd and even, thinking how they would fit in.

Comment: Your question is completely unclear.  Please give an example of solutions (presumably for low $n$).  Even your statement "Find the number of $n$ long sequences of letters $a$, $b$, $c$" is ungrammatical and makes no sense.  Do you mean "sentences of length $n$"?  Or instead there are $n$ different sequences?  And if so, what is "long"?  And if so, how long can each segment be?  Must they all be of the same length?  Please re-write your question, if you expect us to help.

Comment: None of this is remotely clear.  I'll hazard a guess:  when you say "length $n$"  you mean length $3n$ and, specifically, you mean that you have $n$ consecutive permutations of $a,b,c$ subject to some constraint.  Thus if $n=1$ the strings you favor are $bac,cab$ only.  Am I right?

Comment: Assuming my wild guess is correct, then the only good "odd numbered" permutations are $bac,cab$ and the only good "even numbered" permutations are $abc,acb,bca,cab$.  Thus if $n=2$, so you want strings of length $6$, there are two choices for the first three, and four four the second three, so $8$ all in all.

Comment: I voted to close this question until it is clarified and unambiguous.  Otherwise we'll be on a goose chase (as we say in English), with no idea what the poser is thinking.

Comment: As you can see from the comments, nobody can understand what you are asking.  Is there any chance that you can clarify?  For instance...can you clearly and carefully explain what the answer is for $n=1$ and $n=2$?  If you could work those cases for us, we'd probably understand the rules.  If you can not work those cases, well then I think we should just close the question.

Comment: Voting to close the question.

Comment: Well everyone! That is the same question asked on my test, and I am as confused as you are too. Based on my colleagues perspective we are supposed to find the the number of n sequences for those letters. Please keep the question open. Someone else might find a solution to it.

Answer (score 1):

The length of the sequence is $n$.   There are three choices for every letter in even-indexed positions, and two choices for every letter in odd-indexed positions.   So the count of possible sequences is:$$3^{[\text{count of even-indexed positions}]}\times 2^{[\text{count of odd-indexed positions}]}$$

Cases: parity of $n$

- When $n$ is odd, then there are $\tfrac{n-1}{2}$ even-indexed positions, and $\tfrac{n+1}2$ odd-indexed position.
- When $n$ is even, then there are $\tfrac{n}{2}$ even-indexed positions, and $\tfrac{n}2$ odd-indexed position.

So...